# Optimizing GAE Datastore querying repeated fields

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

In one of my NDB models, I have one field whose type is `ndb.JsonProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)`.

This field is an array that on the average case has about 800 elements which look like `{ac: "i", e: [0, 3], ls: ["a"], s: [0, 2], sn: 9, ts: "2018-06-25T22:35:04.855Z"}`. These represent editions in a text editor.

In some parts of my application just a summary of these elements is needed. For example: how many elements have the `ac` property equal to 'x' or how many seconds elapsed between the first and the last element of the array.

My problem is that sometimes I need to get several models, each of them with an array containing about 800 of the elements described previously. So, let's say I need to process 40 models * 800 elements = 32000 elements – this already causes my application to use about 150MB of memory, when GAE allows 128MB to be used.

I tried to do an optimization: I summarize the data once, and keep it stored in a property, because at some point, the array doesn't change anymore. This allows me to use less memory by not accessing the array. But the summary data may become stale when the array is updated – this can be verified by getting the timestamp of last element in the array, and comparing it to the summary timestamp, if it's more recent, then the summary is stale.

**My question is:** in Python 2.7 – more specifically when using NDB – will the whole array be retrieved when I access the last element, as in `elements[-1]`? Or is there a way to lazily load the list from the last to the first element? Or is there a way to optimize the data, so that I don't use so much memory when I need to process it?

Comment: To avoid the problem of stale summary properties you could use [computed properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed) to store them, which are automatically re-calculated every time the entity is updated.

Comment: Side note: You could go above 128M as well by choosing a different [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) - if you really need to.